# Semantic Issue: Cannot find the protocol declaration for ‘ARSessionDelegate’

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

Do anyone know the workaround for the build error on `Xcode`?
All suggestions are welcomed.
E.G: Impossible in that way,  Possible with `Objective-C`, not `Swift`

**Environment:**
Swift:3.2, Xcode:9.2, Unity:2017.3.0f1, iOS:11.2.1

**Condition:**
I’m trying to make Native Plugin for Unity using Swift like this.

> *Unity C# -> Objective-C -> Swift*

For now, I could access the iPhone camera roll from `Unity`.
The Project Name is `GetDepthSample` here.

**Error Detail:**
As soon as I add `ARSessionDelegate` on the class definition,  I got the following error.
[CameraRollSample.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YipK9.png)

**Other Information:**

**GetDepthSample-Swift.h** (generated automatically on Xcode) shows the following error.
[GetDepthSample-Swift.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmGSs.jpg)

It’s possible to jump to Definition of the protocol `ARSessionDelegate`.

Not only `ARSessionDelegate` but also `MetalKit` shows the similar error.

**The original Unity Project**

https://github.com/wapa5pow/CameraRollSample

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what is in your `GetDepthSample-Swift.h` file?

Comment: I posted it on github!:
https://github.com/TproJapan/GetDepthSample/blob/master/GetDepthSample-Swift.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the header that you posted in the comment, it seems to me that maybe you need to include the ARKit framework in the project settings in Xcode. Although this generally tends to work automatically clearly something in your setup has that missing.

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion.

I added the ARKit framework in Xcode -> Build Phases ->Link Binary With Libraries. But couldn't fix the error.

I pushed the latest xcode project on github.
https://github.com/TproJapan/GetDepthSample/tree/master/GetDepthSample

Comment: It failed to push the large size lib files to github, so that I pushed on my Bitbucket rep.
https://bitbucket.org/Shake-Tateda/getdepthsample/src/81a7e59785580c7e5965541821e9635780d26a08/GetDepthSample/?at=master

Comment: This error fixed.
I added **#import <ARKit/ARKit.h>** on top of the **CameraRollViewControllerPlugin.mm** , then succeeded to build.

But I couldn't get arframe information in **func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)**.

With regarding to this issue, I will post as an another question.
Thanks

Comment: Glad I was able to help find the answer :)